# Is there a Raml 1.0 (not 0.8) HTML generator?

Tags: node.js, api, documentation, raml

Somebody knows if is there a version of raml2html to Raml 1.0? I found only tools for Raml 0.8, like **raml2html** or  **raml2md**, but doesn't working for Raml 1.0.

Answer (score 3):

The owner of raml2html and raml2md has left and the two repos are not in maintainance now.

[raml2html](https://github.com/raml2html/raml2html) and [raml2md](https://github.com/raml2html/raml2md) depend on [raml2obj](https://github.com/raml2html/raml2obj/), and [raml2obj](https://github.com/raml2html/raml2obj/) depends on [raml-parser](https://www.npmjs.org/package/raml-parser), which only supports 0.8 right now. The new raml parser is [raml-js-parser-2](https://github.com/raml-org/raml-js-parser-2), however it's still at a beta state

Comment: Well, the owner (me) was looking for new maintainers but never left. The repos are still being maintained, although I am still looking for new maintainers and contributors!

Answer (score 2):

You're probably already aware by now, but yes raml2html and raml2md 4.x work with RAML 1.0 files.

Answer (score 0):

raml2html 1.0 is, I guess, still in experimental phase.
There is a trick for raml2html to work with RAML 1.0 files by disabling the validation on the RAML parser.

We need to change the `raml.loadFile(source)` call in raml2obj to `raml.loadFile(source, {validate: false})`
ref: https://github.com/raml2html/raml2html/issues/156

This link ay help you more: http://forums.raml.org/t/recommended-tool-for-raml-1-0-to-html/1251/8

May be an alternative of raml2html tool here:
https://github.com/PGSSoft/ramlo
It is generating RESTful API documentations written in RAML and supports 1.0